# isomorphism of quaternion algebras

Tags: quaternions, galois-cohomology

I has a question reading 'Galois cohomology-Gille-Szamuely'

[image]

I has a problem as follows.

Let us define a k-algebra homomorphism $\varphi:(a,b) \to (u^2a,v^2b) $ which assigns $ui$ to $i$  and $vj$ to $j$.  $\varphi(ii)=\varphi (a)$ and $\varphi(i)\varphi(i)=uiui=u^2a$ are equal since $\varphi$ is a k-algebra homomorphism so $\varphi (a)$ should be $u^2 a$ which makes $\varphi(i)\varphi(i) =u^2 a  =\varphi(ii)$.

$\varphi$ is not identity homomorphism on $k$ because of $\varphi(a)=au^2$.

I think that $\varphi$ should be identity homomorphism on k(as I understand it is a definition of a morphism of quaternion algebras)

my question is  "$\varphi$ don't need to be identity homomorphism on k?"

Comment: the words homomorphism, isomorphism and morphism are distinct.  i don't know quite what your asking but yes, you want to look at k-algebra homomorphisms.

Comment: Why do you think $\phi(a)=au^2$? The authors denote by  $(a,b)$ the quaternion algebra arising from a choice of $a$ and $b$. In other words
$$(a,b)=\{s_1+s_2i+s_3j+s_4ij\mid s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\in k\}.$$
So $\phi:(a,b)\to(u^2a,v^2b)$ is defined by
$$s_1+s_2i_1+s_3j_1+s_4i_1j_1\mapsto s_1+s_2ui_2+s_3vj_2+s_4uvi_2j_2,$$
where I use subscripts to distinguish the elements $i,j$ of the two $k$-algebras. Consequently $\phi(a)=a$.

Comment: I compute $\varphi(a)=\varphi(i i)=\varphi(i ) \varphi(i )=ui ui=u^2 (i)^2=u^2 a$ so $\varphi(a)=u^2a$

Comment: Hmm. I went in the wrong direction above. We should have $\phi(i_1)=i_2/u$. The language in the excerpt is a bit ambiguous here, but whatever it takes. The idea is anyway that the algeba $(a,b)$ contains anticommuting elements with squares $u^2a$ and $u^2b$.